# How do you combine rows in a group that have a certain condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to generate a report that shows transactions with 2 or more Mode Of Payments and with change. The strange thing about this is these are transactions that used cards and e-wallets as MOPs but were still given change. What I'm having difficulty in is combining the total amount paid in a transaction, leaving the row that shows the amount of change given. To illustrate, say this is the table:

| Receipt No. | MOP | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Cash | 100 |
| 0001 | Cash | -70 |
| 0001 | Card | 500 |
| 0002 | Cash | -50 |
| 0002 | E-Wallet | 300 |
| 0002 | Card | 250 |
| 0003 | Cash | -100 |
| 0003 | Cash | 150 |
| 0003 | Card | 200 |

I want to produce something like this

| Receipt No. | MOP | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Cash | -70 |
| 0001 | Cash, Card | 600 |
| 0002 | Cash | -50 |
| 0002 | E-Wallet, Card | 550 |
| 0003 | Cash | -100 |
| 0003 | Card | 350 |

Reposted this for clarity. I just started learning and using SQL recently so any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean to sum cash and card payment types together for Receipt 0001? You are showing a summation of cash + card equal to 600 and marked as Card.

Comment: The logic is not clear.

Comment: Tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Are you using `SQL Server` or `MySQL` ? You posted the same [closed] question yesterday under `MySQL` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wanted to identify any abnormality in the transactions

The `CTE` `trans` identifies those transactions with more than one `MOP` and with `Amount` negative.

After that, join to the original table, `GROUP BY` [`SIGN(Amount)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to segregate positive Amount from negative

[string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is used to concatenate the `MOP` into comma delimited

```
with trans as
(
    select   receipt_no
    from     transactions
    group by receipt_no
    having count(distinct MOP) > 1
    and    min(Amount) < 0
)
select r.receipt_no, 
       string_agg(MOP, ',') as MOP, 
       sum(t.Amount) as Amount
from   trans r
       inner join transactions t on r.receipt_no = t.receipt_no
group by r.receipt_no, sign(t.Amount)
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=071fdd56ce75b14eaaf6997c910d8144)

---

> I need to generate a report that shows transactions with 2 or more
> Mode Of Payments and with change

You should also explain that `with change` are those line with negative Amount. Not everybody understand your context.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple idea to serve as a tarting point for you (considering SQL Server or SQL Azure database syntax and functions):

```
SELECT 
  [Receipt No.],
  STRING_AGG([MOP], ',') AS [MOPs],
  SUM([Amount]) AS TotalAmount,
FROM (
  SELECT
    [Receipt No.],
    [MOP],
    [Amount],
    CASE WHEN [Amount] < 0 THEN 'Change' ELSE 'Payment' END AS [Type]
  FROM TABLE
) A
GROUP BY [Receipt No.], [Type]
ORDER BY 1;
```